# What's the exact meaning of each 'NotificationOutcome' in Azure per message telemetry?

Tags: android, azure, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

The documentation says

```
Abandoned   NotificationOutcome when the notification sent has been Abondoned
Cancelled   NotificationOutcome when the user cancelled the scheduled send request
Completed   NotificationOutcome when the notification sent has been recevied
DetailedStateAvailable  NotificationOutcome state during DebugSend
Enqueued    NotificationOutcome when notification is intially enqued
NoTargetFound  NotificationOutcome when there are no targets found to send the message
Processing  Processing sent notification
Unknown     Unknown state when State not set
```

I'm concerned with Completed and NoTargetFound at the moment, but unclear on what exactly they mean.

1. If the outcome is 'Completed', does that mean it's been sent successfully to FCM, but not necessarily to the phone?
2. Does FCM give any feedback on notifications to Azure?
3. Can notifications result in a 'Completed' NotificationOutcome but actually not get sent due to an expired FCM token?
4. Does 'NoTargetFound' just mean a device registration wasn't found in the notification hub?

Answer (score 1):

Completed means that the system delivered the message to PNS and it did not receive any error back from PNS. No Target found means that the system was not able to find any device to send notification for the send request. For example you could send a message to a tag foo but there are no device that matches that tag in our system. So  we report that message as no target found.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in our system'? Where is that?